# Save images not properly display on heroku

Tags: heroku, carrierwave

i'm using Rails 3.2.6 and using carrierwave to upload images.When i upload image it is display fine and its image url also working well. But when i push next git commit on heroku.

```
       git push staging master
```

than all images that i had already upload not display and its image path are not working 
why?

Please anyone can tell what's the problem is running.

**Thnaks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst your uploads will work - the moment you push new code, or your application is restarted you will loose any uploads.

Heroku uses an Ephemeral file system, in that each dyno receives a separate copy (slug) of the originally deployed code so uploads would only exist on the dyno that handled the upload (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

You need to use an external persistant data store like Amazon S3, Rackspace Files etc - fortunately with Carrierwave it's trivial to update it to use it as it supports it out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup carrierwave with s3 (https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3)? 
Heroku has a read only file system (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).